# inside FileUpload's SaveAs() and HttpPostedFile.SaveAs()

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, .net-4.0

What is the difference between `FileUpload1.SaveAs()` and `HttpPostedFile.SaveAs()`. I know that both are using for uploading file or files to the web server but I want to know more.

Answer (score 2):

This is what FileUpload does behind the scenes

```
public void SaveAs(string filename) {
     HttpPostedFile f = PostedFile;
     if (f != null) {
          f.SaveAs(filename);
     }
}
```

It is just a wrapper around HttpPostedFile.SaveAs() so there is no difference.

Comment: Thanks Kevin sir for your reply it's help me alot